# Getting dates from "command input"

Tags: date, batch-file

I already created a script to calculate dates but i'm having trouble getting proper input from users. I've created a script to separate inputs.

So lets say the user types in ***/ban myth 1d***

[The script already knows that "1d" is a argument]

I want the script to be able to make a variable called time,where in has the time [in days] that the user inputs.
So if the time is "1d" %time% would equal 1

Or if the user types "1m" %time% would equal 30.
Other examples are:

```
2m=60
1w=7
2w=14
1y=365
```

Any Ideas?

Calculating time would be cool to,but only if you want to.

Comment: Maybe use something more appropriate than batch? PowerShell maybe, or write a program.

Comment: Was thinking about that,but i'm on a challenge to write it completely by batch :P

Comment: Ask if PowerShell is allowed. It's as much "batch" as cmd.exe is.

Comment: Its not. Completely vanilla

Comment: Well, my point is that neither one is "vanilla". They are both command line processors that come with Windows. Cmd is simply primitive and it's a disgrace that it is still being taught in schools.

Comment: I disagree,cmd can do a lot more than you think. P.S Schools hate it,because cmd can sometimes overthrow domains.

Comment: I know very well how much cmd can do. But it's an unnecessary and ugly hassle to do those things. Having to use `SET /A` to do calculations instead of just doing them? Horrible. It wasn't made to be a comprehensive scripting language. In fact, it wasn't made to be a _language_ at all.

Comment: Well Powershell is hideous and excessively wordy. Plus, the default execution policy won't allow scripts to even be run, which is a hassle if you need to push a script to 500 new computers for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure batch solution:

```
rem save the second parameter to a variable so we can get the bits
set _timeSpec=%2

rem get the last character of the timespec == period
set _period=%_timeSpec:~-1%

rem get the number of periods - all but the last character (to cope with 2 digits)
set _numPeriods=%_timeSpec:~0,-1%



set _time=0

if "%_period%"=="d" set /A _time=%_numPeriods%
if "%_period%"=="w" set /A _time=%_numPeriods% * 7
if "%_period%"=="m" set /A _time=%_numPeriods% * 30
if "%_period%"=="y" set /A _time=%_numPeriods% * 365

echo %_time%
```

If you put something in that it doesn't recognise, e.g. 15z it will just fall through and %_time% will still be zero, so you should probably put a test in for that as well.

Update: it's case sensitive, so you probably also want to add in upper case options for each

```
if "%_period%"=="W" set /A _time=%_numPeriods% * 7
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was possible,just couldn't think of it.

Comment: to make `if` case insensitive, just use the `/i`-parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I really like python for this. Here is how to input a start date, start time, and duration and calculate the end date and end time.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

da = raw_input("Start Date [MM_DD_YY]: ")
st = raw_input("Start Time [HH:MM]: ")
id = raw_input("Impact Duration [HH:MM]: ")

startdate = datetime(int('20'+da.split('_')[2]),int(da.split('_')[0]),int(da.split('_')[1]),int(st.split(':')[0]),int(st.split(':')[1]))
enddate = startdate + timedelta(hours=int(id.split(':')[0]),minutes=int(id.split(':')[1]))
startdate_str =  str(startdate.month)+'/'+str(startdate.day)+'/'+str(startdate.year)
starttime_str =  format( startdate , '%H:%M:%S')
endtime_str = format( enddate , '%H:%M:%S')
enddate_str = str(enddate.month)+'/'+str(enddate.day)+'/'+str(enddate.year)
```